# How to make VB.net give 5 significant digits in the textbox output?

Tags: vb.net

I want to have only 5 significant digits in my textbox output. May I know what VB function does this. Thanks

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? What textbox? Please post your current code.

Comment: I expected that this is so common, there is a built in function in VB.net to do that. For a situation that I meet a new people, I will ask what is his/her name. Because it is very common thing every person would have one. That's why I don't want to reinvent the wheel

Comment: By the way, I think my question is clear that I am asking built-in function "May I know what VB function does this" . Right?

Comment: There are several ways of doing this, but it is not clear to me the exact input and the exact output - what datatype are you talking about? And **what have you tried**? We like to help those who first try to help themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Validating event to reformat the entered number.  You'll want to use an ErrorProvider to report input errors back the user.

To get a fixed number of significant digits, you need to dynamically create the formatting string for the number, based on the entered value.  You can use Math.Log10() to calculate the number of digits required in the fraction.  Like this:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Validating(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Validating
    Dim value As Double
    If Not Double.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, value) Then
        ErrorProvider1.SetError(TextBox1, "Please enter a valid number")
        TextBox1.SelectAll()
    Else
        ErrorProvider1.SetError(TextBox1, "")
        Dim intDigits As Integer = 0
        If value <> 0 Then intDigits = CInt(Math.Truncate(Math.Log10(Math.Abs(value))))
        If intDigits >= 0 Then intDigits += 1
        Dim fracDigits = 5 - intDigits
        If fracDigits < 0 Then fracDigits = 0
        Dim format = "F" + fracDigits.ToString()
        TextBox1.Text = value.ToString(format)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that the `math.round` function only rounds the fractional portion of the number. The method I came up with gets the integer portion of a real number, converts it to a decimal and determines the power of 10.

The fractional portion of the number is divided by the same power of 10 and added to the integer portion that was converted to a fraction. Then, you can round that number and multiply by the power of 10 found above to get any real number rounded to the desired significant figures. I added a button to a form to test the function as indicated below:

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim x As Double = InputBox("input a real to round", , , , )
    Dim y As Double
    Dim sfs As Integer = InputBox("input sig figs", , , , )
    y = fSigFig(x, sfs)
    Console.WriteLine(y)
End Sub

'this function converts a real number with no formatting to a real number with a specified number of significant figures
Public Function fSigFig(ByVal areal As Double, ByVal sigfigs As Integer) As Double
    Dim itens As Integer = 0
    Dim intportion As Double = Int(areal) 'this is the integer portion of the number
    Dim decportion As Double = areal - intportion 'this is the fractional portion of the number 
    If intportion < 1 Then 'areal only consists of a fractional portion, round directly
        fSigFig = Math.Round(areal, sigfigs, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
    Else 'convert integer portion of number to a fraction and determine power of 10 required
        While intportion >= 1
            itens += 1
            intportion /= 10
        End While
        'add the integer portion and decimal portion back together as a fraction number divided by 10^itens
        'then round to specified significant figures and multiply by 10^itens
        decportion /= 10 ^ itens
        Dim numbertoround As Double = intportion + decportion
        fSigFig = (10 ^ itens) * Math.Round(numbertoround, sigfigs, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

**First of all, thanks everyone and Merry Christmas. I will mark Hans Passant reply as am answer**

I did think before asking this question. I asked this question was not trying to find someone do the program for me. (But I really thanks Hans Passant). I expected there was a built-in function, it may be called ROUNDTO. I posted the question because I wanted to know the name if the function was exist.

For my application, I did that

```
    Function roundTo(ByVal num As Double) As Double
    If num >= 10000 Then
        Return Math.Round(num)
    Else
        Dim tempnum = num
        Dim counter = 0
        Do
            tempnum = tempnum * 10
            counter = counter + 1
        Loop While tempnum / 10000 < 1
        Return Math.Round(num * 10 ^ (counter)) / (10 ^ (counter))
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: This is not an answer to your question.